# How to prevent a user from downloading a PDF to more than one computer

Tags: drm

I am creating a web site to sell digital articles which are in PDF format and are encrypted.

The solution I am thinking is to let buyer download encrypted PDF file from my web site and then I email him/her a password for him/her to open and read.

I have two concerns here:
1) How can I identify each buyer's computer after they download the article? The purpose is not to allow the same buyer to download from computer B after download from computer A and try to open the file from computer B with the same password as computer A. The goal is to limit buyers to share password with friends. Even his/her friends can download the encryped PDF file, they can not open it with the password.

2) How can I limit a buyer to copy/paste out the content of my PDF file? That is how to disable the 'select' and 'copy' menu of the PDF file? My original file is a MS Word file. When I convert Word to PDF, is there any setting to change to disable 'select' and 'copy'?

Or is there better solutions?

Thank you for your wisdom on this.

-Leo

Comment: The short answer: You can't. (And if I was your customer, I'd leave you if you managed to do this.)

Comment: Is the site coded with PHP, Java or .Net?

Comment: a) Let your users sign a license agreement and then trust them. b) Change your business model. -- Technically, you cannot stop people from copying intellectual property. If there was a surefire way, it would have been adopted by the music industry ages ago.

Comment: This is really a question of PDF DRM, and isn't relevant to java/php/javascript/.net

Comment: Are users allowed to print the PDF?

Comment: Replace your computer, buy your documents all over again. Not even Apple's most restrictive DRM is *that* bad.

Comment: As mentioned, you can set some 'no-copy' and 'no-print' etc settings on a pdf. If this is not sufficient for you, I guess PDF is not the best tech choice here.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the solution is to not let them download the PDF at all. You might want to think about using flash to display the content or maybe something like google books.

If you need to make the content available offline you add an event listener for when the user navigates away and warn them.

Answer (score 1):

A PDF file can contain some restrictions like "not printable" but actually this does not mean it's not printable. As it's viewable on screen, you can do screenshots and then print.

Next to that the data has already left your area of influence so there is not much about what you actually have control.

I have a better suggestion: Instead of the PDF they download a token generating program. When they execute this program they will see a token which changes every minute. If they want to get the information from the document, they call you by phone. You check that token, can mark the user as "used" and then you can read the pages to him.

There still is the risk however that the reading is getting wiretaped, so you need to watermark the audio-transmission so you can track those users who are responsible for copyright infringement.

So it's a bit of a question what you actually want and what your users want probably. I have the feeling this can not be really solved technically.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want them to download the PDF, there really is no way to keep them from opening it on different computers.   I would suggest a web-based solution that uses a database and cookies to keep track of the users machine.  If you absolutely must allow them to download the file, then you need to build a viewer in another language (such as C) and have that record the MAC address of the machines motherboard.   Then it will do a check that the MAC address of the machine opening the file matches, otherwise display ACCESS DENIED or similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive answer to this. If someone wanted to, they could printscreen all the content anyway. If you want to limit the use of passwords, just check the IP of when someone logs in. If a user has logged in more than once at the same time with IPs all over the place, do some useful action to handle this.